# Python function that solves an equation and records the best answer with corresponding input

Tags: python, list, algorithm, function, equation

```
list = [[2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3]]
answers = []
for pqr in list:
    p,q,r = pqr
    result = 2*p + 3*q + 7*r
    if result > 0:
        Output = result 
        answers.append([Output]) 
print (Output)
print (answers)
```

Hi everyone. I have the code above but it hasn't given me the desired output. I'm trying to get the two results from the output after substituting the values in each list to the equation. I'm only getting a single output at the moment.

I want to store the 2 answers as shown above. I also want to store the corresponding input value that gives me the highest value of the answer.
I'm using this to implement an algorithm; the maximum value and corresponding input in this case will be used in the next iteration as my best value yet.
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You assign to `function` but then you never use it.  And what is `result`?  That variable is not defined.

Comment: I can't understand what the code is supposed to do. For the given input `[[2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3]]`, exactly what should the result be, and why? Please read [ask] and [mre], and also make sure that the code you post is [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - as indentation is crucial in Python. There seem to be many things wrong in this code, most of which are typos or simple logical errors that [you should](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) try to [figure out yourself first](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @JohnGordon, sorry about the typo. The question has been edited and the variables clearly defined. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's how your script should work, it should look like this:

```
ls = [[2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3]]
answers = []
for pqr in ls:
    p,q,r = pqr
    result = 2*p + 3*q + 7*r
    if result > 0:
        Output = result 
        answers.append([Output]) 
print(Output)
print(answers)
```

First, don't shadow `list` constructor. Use another variable, such as `ls`. It's recomended that you use antoher variable name in case you need to use the `list()` constructor later on.

Also, beware of the Python Identation. You script just needed a little identation to work, besides the variables that were not defined.

This should be your output:

```
29
[[41], [29]]
```

`29` is the last value assigned to `Output` variable. The second print is the list `answers`'s contents.